# Column comparison with different query times

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization, charindex

I have a where statement that utilises `charindex` on a column (`where charindex(A , B) != 0`). However, there is a third column C , that is the same variable type and size as B, but takes a lot longer to process, 10 seconds for the first, 5 minutes for the second.

This C column is created using an case statement based on column B. Why is there such a time difference between both queries?

```
--10 Seconds
select distinct  A, B, C, D
into Table4
from Table1, Table2, Table3
inner join Table4
    on Table2.column1 = Table3.column2
where (CHARINDEX(A, B) != 0)

--5 Minutes
select distinct A, B, C, D
into Table4
from Table1, Table2, Table3
inner join Table4
    on Table2.column1 = Table3.column2
where (CHARINDEX(A, C) != 0)
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use modern join syntax.

Comment: `inner` is not valid, this query cannot run?! and see [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to kick.

Comment: For performance questions please [upload](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) the actual execution plan.  There are a lot of reasons the different queries could have very different performance times.

Comment: This is an example querry , sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: You still need to make sure you example query works.

Comment: Check for 1 column in another is going to require a complete table scan i.e. no use of indexes, hence will certainly be slow.

Comment: I understand that it will be slow , but why would there be such a huge difference between the comparison of two different columns with the same datatype and similar size?

Comment: you're creating a multiple cartesian product not to mention joining table3 twice. As to why - the execution plan will tell you, and us - you've been asked for it already.

Comment: And now you've edited the query to join with `table4` - which cannot exist, if it did the `select... into` syntax would fail. I suggest if you want accurate help you provide an accurate query.

Comment: I cannot post the execution plan due to sensitive data , and as i mentioned before , the query above is for demonstration of the usage of Charindex on my main query , it is not functional.  The point that i am trying to make is that i see no reason for one comparison being slower that the other , and i am seeking help and possible problems that may cause that.

Comment: Unfortunately without the actual execution plan or a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) no one can give you an accurate answer; have you even looked at the execution plan? Have you examined the differences in logical IO for each table and how the predicates were applied or filtered or indexes used in each? The plan XML is editable text you can replace/obfuscate object names if you really have to.

Comment: You can use SentryOne Plan Explorer to anonymize the plan. This question is absolutely not answerable without the fast and slow plans (you can share these via https://pastetheplan.com) and also table and index definitions.

Comment: Basically what is probably going on is that the first query is able to utilize an index but the second is not, therefore the query is slow. But without the above detail we cannot tell for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the input Charlieface, i will look it up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution could be making the calculated column persistent and creating an index on it as well.